# Javascript Word Counter w/ enabled Disabled buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is;
-Right arrow disable until I start typing
-when I click that counts the words in the text box and image changes to the left arrow
-when I click the left arrow that restarts the progress.

Right now it doesn't really display the result it just shows that for a second and changes the image but auto restarts everything in a second and right arrow button is enabled all the time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {
    var words = $.trim($("textarea").val()).split(" ");
    document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = words.length;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordcounter">
  <form action="" method="get" name="frm" onSubmit="TextCount();">
    <!--Text Area-->
    <textarea id="mytext"></textarea><br/>
    <!--Image Flipped Here-->
    <input type="image" id="submit" src="imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_right_T.png" alt="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('submit').src='imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_left_T.png'">
    <br/>
    <!--Result-->
    <div id="resultDiv">0</div>&nbsp;Characters
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've configured your form to perform a `GET` request. When you click your `input type="image"` element, the form's submission event fires and performs the GET request to the page. Since there's no handler code for these requests, your page effectively goes through a "refresh" as you've noticed.

To prevent this behavior, capture the `event` object from the fired `click` event and use it to `preventDefault()` in your callback function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var words = $.trim($("textarea").val()).split(" ");
    document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = words.length;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordcounter">
  <form action="" method="get" name="frm" onSubmit="TextCount();">
    <!--Text Area-->
    <textarea id="mytext"></textarea><br/>
    <!--Image Flipped Here-->
    <input type="image" id="submit" src="imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_right_T.png" alt="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('submit').src='imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_left_T.png'">
    <br/>
    <!--Result-->
    <div id="resultDiv">0</div>&nbsp;Characters
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better off using focus instead of click, in case the user uses tab or something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').blur(function () {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $("input").focus(function () {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        var words = $.trim($("textarea").val()).split(" ");
        $("#resultDiv").innerHTML = words.length;
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');
        if(imageSource == "imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_left_T.png"){
            $(this).attr("src","imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_right_T.png");
        }else{
            $(this).attr("src","imgs/arrow_button_metal_green_left_T.png");
        }
    });
});
```

You can get resultDiv easier with jQuery.